# angularfire: Having trouble getting a Firebase array from my factory with $asArray()

Tags: arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've got a factory that gets my data from Firebase, and I want my controller to be able to access it. However, when I console.log the data in my controller, it isn't the Array[10] that I would expect it to be, but rather an Array with keys 0,1,2,..10, $$added, $$error, $$moved,... and so on. However, when I skip out on using the factory, and use $asArray() method on my firebase ref directly in my controller it shows up nicely as an Array[10]

In my factory, this is what it looks like..

```
var listingsref = new Firebase("https://something.firebaseio.com");
var sync2 = $firebase(listingsref);
var products = sync2.$asArray();
factory.getProducts = function(){
    return products;
};
```

Controller

```
$scope.products = marketFactory.getProducts();
```

console.log($scope.products) in my controller should be Array[10], but instead it's an Array with the data + a lot more $$ methods. Anyone know what's going on? Thanks

EDIT: Full Factory File

```
(function(){
var marketFactory = function($firebase){
    var listingsref = new Firebase("https://something.firebaseio.com");
    var sync2 = $firebase(listingsref);
    var products = sync2.$asArray();

    var factory = {};
    factory.getProducts = function(){
        console.log(products);
        return products;
    };

    factory.getProduct = function(productId){
        for(var x = 0; x<products.length ;x++){
            if(productId == products[x].id){
                return {
                    product:products[x],
                    dataPlace:x
                };
            }
        }
        return {};
    };

    factory.getNextProduct = function(productId, e){
        var currentProductPlace = factory.getProduct(productId).dataPlace;
        if (e=="next" && currentProductPlace<products.length){
            return products[currentProductPlace+1];
        }

        else if(e=="prev" && currentProductPlace>0){
            return products[currentProductPlace-1];
        }
        else{
            return {};
        }
    };

    factory.componentToHex = function(c){
        var hex = c.toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    };

    factory.rgbToHex = function(r,g,b){
        return "#" + factory.componentToHex(r) + factory.componentToHex(g) + factory.componentToHex(b);
    };

    factory.hexToRgb = function(hex) {
        if(hex.charAt(0)==="#"){
            hex = hex.substr(1);
        }
        var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
        var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
        var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
        var b = bigint & 255;

        return r + ", " + g + ", " + b;
    };

    factory.parseRgb = function(rgb){
        rgb = rgb.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var red = parseInt(rgb.split(',')[0]);
        var green = parseInt(rgb.split(',')[1]);
        var blue = parseInt(rgb.split(',')[2]);

        return {
            r:red,
            g:green,
            b:blue
        };
    };

    return factory;
};

marketFactory.$inject = ['$firebase'];
angular.module('marketApp').factory('marketFactory', marketFactory);
}());
```

Comment: Can you list the code for the full factory? I think I know what the problem is but I need to confirm.

Comment: Sure, I just edited the post.

Comment: Pretty much everything here is incorrect. Please have a look at [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) and try to use the lib as designed. For example, there is already a method to get items by id, the id should be `$id`, the factory methods you've created should be added using `$extendFactory`, and debugging should be done with something like `{{products|json}}` in the view, or `$loaded(console.log)` in the service. A little documentation goes a long way.

Answer (score 7):

This snippet gets a synchronized [AngulareFire array](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#firebasearray) of products:

```
var products = sync2.$asArray();
```

The AngularFire documentation is a bit off on this point: what you get back from `$asArray()` is not an array, but the promise of an array. At some point in the future your `products` variable will contain an array. This is done because it may take (quite) some time for your array data to be downloaded from Firebase. Instead of blocking your code/browser while the data is downloading, it returns a wrapper object (called a *promise*) and just continues.

Such a promise is good enough for AngularJS: if you simply bind `products` to the scope and `ng-repeat` over it, your view will show all products just fine. This is because AngularFire behind the scenes lets AngularJS know when the data is available and Angular then redraws the view.

But you said:

> `console.log($scope.products)` in my controller should be Array[10]

That is where you're mistaken. While AngularFire ensures that its `$asArray()` promise works fine with AngularJS, it doesn't do the same for `console.log`. So your `console.log` code runs before the data has been downloaded from Firebase.

If you really must log the products, you should wait until the promise is resolved. You this this with the following construct:

```
products.$loaded().then(function(products) {
    console.log(products);
});
```

When you code it like this snippet, the data for your products will have been downloaded by the time `console.log` runs.

*Note that the object will still have extra helper methods on it, such as `$add`. That is normal and also valid on an array. See [the documentation for FirebaseArray](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray) for more information on what the methods are, what they're for an how to use them.*

Comment: The second code snippet logs as though I put just console.log(products)... but I've noticed that when I open a new tab and then go to the page (as opposed to refreshing), console.log shows Array[10], but when I expand it everything seems to be the same.. 0,1,2,.. $$ add, etc. That's so weird! But you're also saying that having all the $$ methods is normal and that the array should still work right? Anyway... ng-repeat seems to work now.

Comment: Those extra methods on the array are indeed normal. The fact that you do see the items when you open another tab is also expected: by the time you open that tab, the data has loaded. Please take some time to read and understand the documentation I linked. You would also benefit from @firebase's new Firebase+Angular tutorial. Though it doesn't use AngularFire, it explains the basic operations really wel. See https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlBFDsVuN7bWfhC6RqEfPkS37qG5Y8w4v

Comment: Great explanation Frank. Hope the author upvotes and accepts your post, considering the time and energy you've put into it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So I edited the code in the plnkr at http://plnkr.co/M4PqojtgRhDqU475NoRY.

The main differences are the following:

```
// Add $FirebaseArray so we can extend the factory
var marketFactory = function($firebase, $FirebaseArray){
var listingsref = new Firebase("https://something.firebaseio.com");

// Actually extend the AngularFire factory and return the array
var MarketFactory = $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory(factory);
return function() {
  var sync = $firebase(listingsref, {arrayFactory: factory});

  return sync.$asArray();
};
```

Check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-extending-factories for more information on extending AngularFire entries. You will likely need to make some adjustments to the rest of the factory code.

Comment: I'm probably too much of a noob... after reading the docs, I still don't really understand what extending this factory is for, but I guess I only really needed ng-repeat to work for me right now and after updating my directives with my current factory it seems to work okay.